How do I do the Destiny 2 speed strat for Crucible?
I remember from some videos a long time ago that there's a way to make yourself and your teammates faster immediately off of spawn in PvP, but I can't seem to find where or how.
I don't mean Dunemarchers or Transversive steps, as they only apply to yourself, I mean something that can make your entire team faster the moment you spawn in.

Sounds like a cheat to me As only viable options I can think of are things like sword skating with eager edge, but wouldn't work in PVP as you've got no heavy ammo. Or Arc Amplified speed boost, but would require an arc kill I think. Then things like lightweight frames or stompees etc

The source is the ascension prismatic class aspect. Using dodge in the air boosts you into the air, and then grants you and all nearby allies amplified, and thus a speed boost. All other players who also spec into amplified, including those on an arc subclass and yourself, will benefit as though they earned the amplified buff themself. So, if an arc aspect grants damage resist while amplified for example, it will work. The aspect is available on arc and prismatic hunter.
